# initiate transfer or bulk transfer with rave flutterwave

Tags: flutterwave

being going through the docs of flutterwave for bulk transfer and intiate transfer and still cant get a clear explanation on how this can be done.Anybody with a sample code or some explanation will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to implement a transfer with flutterwave APIs then you can use the available SDKs provided by flutterwave on their Github repo. I would illustrate how you can do so using the PHP SDK for a simple single transfer demo but you can use the same approach for any of the SDKs.

First, you download the SDK from the Github repo and include it in your project. You should add your keys to the .env file. Then import the required files into the file where you want to initiate a transfer.

```
    require_once('Flutterwave/api/Transfer.php'); 
    use Flutterwave\Transfer;
```

Then you can initiate a transfer with the following code

```
    $single = new Transfer();
    $result = $single->singleTransfer($array);
    $trx = json_decode($result, true);
```

The above code instantiates a new transfer, passes your request as an arary in the `$array` variable and stores the result in the `$result` variable. The result is a json so it is converted into an array `$trx`, from here you can print your response or pass it to another function.

kindly note that transfers work with Webhook. A Webhook is an HTTP callback: an HTTP POST that occurs when something happens; a simple event-notification via HTTP POST.

So the status of your transfer is sent to your webhook URL which you have to add in your rave dashboard under your settings>webhook section.

Answer (score 0):

well i eventually sent a mail to thier customer service and had a direct call to one of thier developers and he sent me a medium post with the exact steps

https://medium.com/@emereuwaonueze/simple-payroll-system-for-a-single-transfer-using-flutterwaves-rave-php-sdk-e1b98a1befe4